# Prompt for calculations present in the context for llama2:13b-chat

Tags: prompt, llama

Having below json object , in which one of the object is having a calculation where it need to give the calculated answer .To this need to write a good prompt to obtain the value.
{

```
"Key": "Atom2",
"Value": "1.000%",
"Score % (Key)": 88.44911194,
"Score % (Value)": 88.44911194
```

},
{

```
"Key": "Atom1",
"Value": "7.750%",
"Score % (Key)": 82.35554504,
"Score % (Value)": 82.35554504
```

},
{

```
"Key": "Atom Total",
"Value": "Sum of Atom1 and Atom2",
"Score % (Key)": 82.35554504,
"Score % (Value)": 82.35554504
```

}

My question is ,when I ask 'What is the value of Effective Interest Rate',it should give calculated value.Prompt should not be static, it should be dynamic whenever such type of calculations need to be performed.